# tracking user input and offer word completion- angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I am new in angular and I need some help.
Lets say I have a DB that contains a list of numbers and I want to use this list for word completion.

assume this is my form:

```
          <!-- FORM -->
          <form>

                <!-- CODE -->
                  <label>code</label>
                  <input type="text" name="codeInput" placeholder="please insert your code..." >

                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <button type="submit" >Submit
                </button>
         </form>
```

upon the user inserts at least 5 chars I want to make an ajax call to `offers.php` to retrieve the offers and display them.

**note that the ajax call is before submitting the form**

The php code is working... I am stuck on the client side.

I know that I should do something like:

```
                            $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : 'offers.php',
                        data    : $.param(code),  
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
                        })
                        .success(function(data) 
                          {
                            //display the data somehow...
                         });
```

I just can't figure out how to connect  all the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OliverJ90's answer there should be a small change. Do this in your html:

```
<form>
<!-- CODE -->
    <label>code</label>
    <input type="text" name="codeInput" placeholder="please insert your code..." ng-model="someValue" ng-change="myFunc()" >
    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then your javascript will be like this

```
$scope.myFunc = function(){
    //Do the following if $scope.someValue.length >= 5
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'offers.php',
        data    : $scope.someValue,  
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
    }).success(function(data) {
           //display the data somehow...
    });
}
```

Basically someValue variable will provide a two way data-binding to your input box. that is, if someone changes value in text box, the variable value will change, and if someone changes variable value, input box value will change. This is the reason we have used ng-model. ng-change is just like calling a function on change event, but this is provided by angular.

Please note that, ng-change reuires ng-model, without which it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Method 1:

Bind to the input element:

```
<input ng-model="yourValue">
```

And in the controller watch for changes on `yourValue`

```
$scope.$watch(yourValue, function () {
   //check length and call your function that makes the http request.
});
```

Method 2:

Use ng-change

```
<input ng-change="checkValue()" ng-model="yourValue">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.checkValue = function () {
  //do what you need to do.
}
```

Comment: $scope.$watch is not recommended. I'd rather use ngChange.